# Loop in memory addresses while using array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure

My question is a conceptual one(just for my knowledge).
Is it possible that we get a loop in memory addresses while using an array of pointers to point to multiple linked lists?

Suppose I have some code like this:

```
 struct linkedList{
     int data;
     char name[20];
     struct linkedList *next;
    };
struct linkedList *head[10];
```

Is it possible that 2 or more pointers in above declaration may end up pointing to same addresses?

If so, how to prevent this situation?

Comment: You prevent it by writing code that doesn't assign the same address to multiple different pointers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C: How to check if an array has any duplicates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199403/in-c-how-to-check-if-an-array-has-any-duplicates)

Comment: @KerrekSB : Hi, thanks for ur valuable comment, but can u please provide some pseudo code or valuable link to study it?

Comment: I think you should study dynamic memory allocation in C before trying anything with linked lists, because certainly it's not common knowledge for you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course it's possible. That would be called a "circular list", and is sometimes very useful.

It can be prevented by writing code to detect such a situation.

Comment: A much better explanation of a "circular list" can be found [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19399220/596781).

Comment: @unwind: Sir, I know Circular Linked List, but here, it is unintentional generation of loop. and is not acceptable.